# url was not normalized error when using intellij but not when using STS

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-security

The developed website  works fine on remote server and local machine (when using STS IDE) , recently I started use Intellij IDEA (I created a duplicate of the website code with no any changes ), I started getting the URL was not normalized error.

Does intellij handles Spring security somehow differently than STS ? or what could be the cause?

I don't want use custom httpfirewal .

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                        .dataSource(dataSource);

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // URLs matching for access rights
    http.authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers( "/", "/contact","/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/accounts").hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_USER","ADMIN_USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // form login
            .csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/index")
            .failureUrl("/index?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            // logout
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");


}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

and this is from the properties :

```
     # Spring MVC view prefix.
     spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/
     # Spring MVC view suffix.
     spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

the error is :

```
 org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.
```

P.S: I'm using JDK8 ,Spring Boot 2,Spring Security ,thymeleaf,intellij U 2019.2

Comment: You developed a website? And disabled CSRF? I think you have deeper problems here...

Comment: Also, Java 8 is long deprecated.

Comment: @Boris The Spider . ..                                                                                                                 
 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html [Note]
If you are using Spring MVC <form:form> tag or Thymeleaf 2.1+ and are using EnableWebSecurity, the CsrfToken is automatically included for you (using the CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor).

Comment: Unless of course you disable CSRF and therefore don't validate it at the server

Answer (score 0):

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.
```

Which IDE to use should not have any differences for running the same source codes on the embeddable server configured by springboot. This error happens when the HTTP requests that send to server is not normalised which the URL contains character sequences like `./`, `/../` , `//` or `/.`  So I doubt that it is due to you are using different URL to browse the app. For example, you are accidentally adding a '/' in the URL such as `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app//index.html`

You can change to use a less secure `HttpFirewall` to avoid such checking by :

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.httpFirewall(new DefaultHttpFirewall());
    //another configuration .....
}
```

*P.S. Though it is called `DefaultHttpFirewall` , it is not the default `HttpFirewall` used by Spring Security since 4.2.4 which is less secured than the actual default `StrictHttpFirewall`*

Comment: ...thanks, actually not all containers handles the DefaultHttpFirewall in a secure way. I do know about the extra slash issue ,but If there is one then should arise a problem on the STS IDE ,which made me think probably intellij .Anyway will dig deeper for a solution :) thanks